# Trying to convert a list which contains only one int, within a list to just an int within the list

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a list which contains both ints and also lists of ints within the list.

I am trying to make a method which checks if there are any 1 number lists within the list, and converts that one number list into just an int. So it is no longer a list within the list.

I am using the below code as a guide, but this code works with a matrix and mine is a 3d list.

```html
# Process grid with Possible array values as cells are solved
for row in range(0, GRIDSIZE):
   for col in range(0, GRIDSIZE):
      # Found correct cell value = Only 1 possible value
      if np.size(P[row, col]) == 1:
         singleton = P[row][col][0]
         grid[row][col] = singleton
         # Remove from Possible list
         P[row, col].remove(singleton)
```

This is what I'm trying to do but I get indexerror: invalid index to scalar variable:

```html
    for row in range(0,9):
        for col in range(0,9):
                    if np.size((values[row][col])) == 1:
                        singleton = values[row][col][0]
                        values[row][col] = singleton
```

Also for the 'remove from possible list' part, is there a simple pythonic command i can do to remove that singleton element from the 2d list?

This is what the list looks like at the moment:

```html
[[[7], 8, 5, [6], 1, 3, [2, 6], [4], 9], [6, 3, 4, [8, 9], [8, 9], 2, 1, 7, 5], [[1], 2, [1, 9], 5, 7, 4, [6], 3, [8, 6]], [2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 7, 9, 5, 1], [9, 6, [1], 4, 5, 8, [7], 2, 3], [3, 5, 7, 2, [9], [1], 4, 8, [6]], [5, 7, 3, 1, [4], [6], 8, 9, 2], [4, 9, 6, [8, 7], 2, 5, 3, 1, [7]], [8, 1, 2, [7], 3, 9, 5, 6, 4]]
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code does not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
original_list = [[[7], 8, 5, [6], 1, 3, [2, 6], [4], 9], [6, 3, 4, [8, 9], [8, 9], 2, 1, 7, 5], [[1], 2, [1, 9], 5, 7, 4, [6], 3, [8, 6]], [2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 7, 9, 5, 1], [9, 6, [1], 4, 5, 8, [7], 2, 3], [3, 5, 7, 2, [9], [1], 4, 8, [6]], [5, 7, 3, 1, [4], [6], 8, 9, 2], [4, 9, 6, [8, 7], 2, 5, 3, 1, [7]], [8, 1, 2, [7], 3, 9, 5, 6, 4]]

new_list = [[elem[0] if (isinstance(elem, list) and len(elem)==1) else elem for elem in sublist] for sublist in original_list ]

# new_list
"""
[[7, 8, 5, 6, 1, 3, [2, 6], 4, 9],
 [6, 3, 4, [8, 9], [8, 9], 2, 1, 7, 5],
 [1, 2, [1, 9], 5, 7, 4, 6, 3, [8, 6]],
 [2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 7, 9, 5, 1],
 [9, 6, 1, 4, 5, 8, 7, 2, 3],
 [3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 1, 4, 8, 6],
 [5, 7, 3, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 2],
 [4, 9, 6, [8, 7], 2, 5, 3, 1, 7],
 [8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5, 6, 4]]"""
```

**EDIT**: Using for loops:

```
new_list = []
for sublist in original_list:
    new_sublist = []
    for elem in sublist:
        if (isinstance(elem, list) and len(elem) == 1):
            new_sublist.append(elem[0])
        else:
            new_sublist.append(elem)
    new_list.append(new_sublist)
```

Comment: Thank you, if I may ask one more query, how do I check if all the values within new_list are now of length 1? I need it for a while loop to stop when there are no more lists within the list that have more than one value.

Comment: you can define a recursive function